# How to select value in dropdown list (select2) when value is found?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, jquery-select2

I'm working on a small angular project, and I've come to a part where I need to filter and display found person/customer.

My modal looks like this:

[image]

What I need to achieve here is:

1.) Enter a number code, for example, 123 and check for a customer with a code like that and display it in dropdown which is select2.

2.) I'm getting a list of all persons when this modal is shown and my code looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'screen-person',
  templateUrl: './ screen-person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ screen-person.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {
  private id: string;
  private listOfPersons: Array<Person>;

  constructor(private _personsService: PersonsService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  show() {
    $('#' + this.id).modal('show');
    // Here I get all of the persons when modal is shown
    this._personsService.getAll().subscribe(listOfPersons => this.listOfPersons = listOfPersons);
  }
}
```

When I enter a code and get results from a list I would like to select corresponding row, for example if I enter code that belongs to Person 1 than select Person 1 and show it in a dropdown as selected.

[image]

I'm filtering/searching for person like this:

```
searchForPersons(filterBy: string) {
    // We are using array .filter method to create a new array with elements
    this.customers = this.listOfPersons.filter((person: Person) =>
      person.cardNumber.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(filterBy) !== -1);
  }
```

And In my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
          <input #code type="text" class="form-control dash-form-control" id="" placeholder="" (keyup.enter)="searchForPersons(code.value)" autofocus>
          <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <select id="personSelect" class="form-control dash-form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
              <option selected disabled>Search...</option>
              <option [value]="person.id" *ngFor="let person of customers ">{{person.title}}</option>
            </select>

          </div>
        </div>
```

So guys one more time, how can I select found person in a dropdown value, so I don't need to open dropdown to look for it in filtered list and click on it.

Thanks, guys
Cheers

Comment: You can just bind typed value of `input` along with your `select`.

Comment: @Pengyy How that might look ?

Comment: refer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xnpyqh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @Pengyy Its awesome and it works in general, but unfortunatelly it does not working as expected with select2 on <select> but this is helpful also!